# navigation bar background did not change

Tags: image, background, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

i have a navigation bar, i want to change it using image, i was implement this code

```
self.navBar.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"flower.png"].CGImage;
```

but the background is still didn't change. the hierarchy of navigation bar are :
- UINavigationBar
- UINavigationItem
- UISegementControl

i already set an outlet in every part in that hierarchy.. 
is there something wrong???

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692517/change-navigation-bar-background-image-on-each-navigation

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've used quite succesfully:

```
CALayer *backgroundImageLayer;
backgroundImageLayer = [CALayer layer];
backgroundImageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44);
backgroundImageLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
backgroundImageLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"barImage.png"] CGImage];
backgroundImageLayer.zPosition = -5.0;
[myNavigationConroller.navigationBar.layer addSublayer:test];
```

The key was setting the zPosition to -5.0, although any negative value should work. It causes the backgroundImageLayer **not** to interfere with UINavigationBar's buttons and label.