# Change Navigation bar Background image on each navigation

Tags: iphone, image, background, navigation

I am working on iPhone app. I have added Navigation bar Background image

With interface: -

`@interface UINavigationBar (backgroundImageWithTitle)`

And method: -

`- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`

By this method Navigation bar background images is being set one time.

I want to call it from different `.m` files for assigning different images on bar.

How it can be implemented?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember to accept answers to the questions you have asked! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CustomNavigation.h

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


    @interface UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCustomDraw){

    }

    @end
```

CustomNavigation.m

```
    @implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCustomDraw)

    - (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

        [self setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5f
                                           green: 0.5f
                                            blue:0 
                                           alpha:1]];

        if ([self.topItem.title length] > 0) {


            if ([self.topItem.title isEqualToString:@"First"]) {

                [[UIImage imageNamed:@"First.png"] drawInRect:rect];

            }

            else if ([self.topItem.title isEqualToString:@"Second"]) {

                [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Second.png"] drawInRect:rect];                   

            }




            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
            UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
            [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 20.0];
            label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:1];
            label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            label.text = self.topItem.title;
            self.topItem.titleView = label;





        } 


        else {
            [[UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.png"] drawInRect:rect];
            self.topItem.titleView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
        }



    }

    @end
```

if u want to First.png to set navigationBar background image in FirstViewController then

in ur FirstViewController.m

```
        -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

        [super viewWillAppear:animated];



            self.title=@"First";
            [self.navigationController.navigationBar drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    }
```

if u want to Second.png to set navigationBar background image in SecondViewController then

in ur SecondViewController.m

```
        -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

        [super viewWillAppear:animated];



            self.title=@"Second";
            [self.navigationController.navigationBar drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but its calling for firstviewcontroller correctly but not for secondviewcontroller. How it can be called second time?

Comment: verify the second png is exists and verify the spelling of first and second

Comment: Sorry, its not working I have checked each thing. Am I missing any other settings or linking?

Comment: so i have answered ur question or not?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 5 this will not work but the good news is that there is a simple way of doing this

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"name"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

NOTE: This will only work on iOS 5 and above so make sure you check iOS version if you want to be backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Or other option so that code runs only incase of iOS 5

```
if([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) //iOS >=5.0
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar-Landscape.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"name"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

It works fine for iOS 5.0 but got crashed in iOS 4.3 or below.

You have either set conditional i.e for

**iOS 5**

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"name"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

**else**

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"name"]];

but still there is issue that it shows line under image.

Or you can do in this way

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES; 
UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
imgView.image = image;
[tempView addSubview:imgView];
[navBar clearBackgroundImage];
[navBar addSubview:tempView];
[tempView release];
```

Comment: Since "appearance" is only available in iOS 5, then the only thing that works is the last codeblock you posted - But that block has the problem that any back buttons don't work which defeats the point of the navigationcontroller - Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: if([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) //iOS >=5.0
    {
        //[[UINavigationBar appearance] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar-Landscape.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];   
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way

```
if([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) //iOS >=5.0
{
    //[[UINavigationBar appearance] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar-Landscape.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];   

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
}
```

and in else case you can add previous code i.e setBackgroundImage ....

Answer (score 0):

Using ***(SDK 3.2.5.)*** - In one of my Apps I needed navigationBar with custom image both in **landscape** and **portrait**.

What I did was:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (BackgroundImage)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    UIImage *image;

    if(self.frame.size.width == 320) //for iPhone - portrait will have 320 pix width.
    {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"portraitNavigationBar.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"landscapeNavigationBar.png"];
    }

    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

Luckily my app supports rotation - so, when rotating - navigation bar automatically redraws itself.

But to manually redraw it - you can also call :

```
[navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsDisplay];
```