# MFMailComposeViewController + UINavigationController iPhone

Tags: iphone

I used custom navigation bar within my application,

```
// appdelegate.h

@implementation UINavigationBar(customNavBar)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{    
    UIImage *navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar.png"];
    [navBarImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

It works fine, but when I use a MFMailComposeViewController for sending an email, it appears with custom navigation bar. Here I don't want the customized navigation bar, I want it to be default.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example of custom navigation bar for each navigation.

in your case you have to modify that code to your needs.

[Change Navigation bar Background image on each navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692517/change-navigation-bar-background-image-on-each-navigation/6693099#comment-7924066)

Comment: welcome.for instant help go for http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/conversation/do-u-want-instant-help-for-ur-question-or-r-u-new-bee-to-iphone-ipad-develop