# Changing background of navigation item and adding image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, navigationcontroller

I have a Root View controller, I need to know about changing its blue background to an image or changing its color and also want to add an image to its right side.
For example in the below image i need to change the background of text Root View Controller to another image or change its color and add a small icon on right side of the Root View Controller text. How should I go about it? I have gone through [Change Navigation bar Background image on each navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692517/change-navigation-bar-background-image-on-each-navigation) but still having trouble implementing it.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

**Viewcontroller.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

[image: This is my storyboard]

Comment: Did you try this? [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage: @"navImage"  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: assume ur working on iOS 5+?

Comment: I'm using xcode 4.2 need to upgrade soon :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting any of these codes into `ViewWillAppear/ViewDidAppear/didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`(in case of appDelegate).

1)`navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"urtitlebar.png"]];`

OR

2)

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"urtitlebar.png"]];
[image setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
[myView addSubview:image];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:myView];
```

OR

3)

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"urtitlebar.png"];
[navBar setBackgroundImage:image];
```

**EDIT**:(in case you're using old version of SDK say 3.2.5)

Create the subview of `UINavigationBar`and override the method called -`drawRect:(CGRect)rect` with,

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (BackgroundImage)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    UIImage *navBarImage;


        image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"urNavigationBar.png"];
    }
    [navBarImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
```

@end

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm almost close to the solution with help of your code, but have some little trouble, in your 2nd answer is it possible to load the setFrame from right side? And in your 3rd answer I am getting this error "receiver type UINavigationBar for instance message doesn't declare a method setBackgroundImage"

Comment: [image setFrame:CGRectMake(276, 0, 44, 44)];

Comment: ya, I have already adjust that too [image setFrame:CGRectMake(275, 0, 44, 44)], jst wanted to know if its possible to load it from right side, its fine. Any idea about the error, do I have to import any other class?

Comment: yes, I am getting this error "receiver type UINavigationBar for instance message doesn't declare a method setBackgroundImage"

Comment: use  [navBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 this instead..(for ARC)

Comment: http://sebastiancelis.com/2009/12/21/adding-background-image-uinavigationbar/ ==> looks awesome...just now i found this...good luck...

Answer (score 0):

Try This code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of AppDelegate.m for custom image on navigation bar.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

You can also add custom button as bar button.

```
 // create a custom button in viewDidLoad of your ViewController in which you want to place a custom bar button
 UIButton *customBackBtn =[[UIButton alloc] init];
[customBackBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
customBackBtn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 52, 31);

// set this customized button as BarButton
UIBarButtonItem *backBtn =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customBackBtn];
[customBackBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn;
```

Thats It.

Comment: thanks for your reply, in your first statement is it possible to position the image, for eg Now the image display from top to 75% but I need to display only the center part. And for second part, I know to add custom button, I'm trying to add an UIimage on right side instead of bar button, is it possible?